# Setting a virtual server on windows 7

Tags: virtualization

I need to give my developer access to setup a web server on my machine, rather than interfere with my environment I would like to offer him a virtual server. What software (free) can I use to do this? e.g. would http://www.virtualbox.org/ do the job? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VirtualBox, Microsoft's VirtualPC, and VMware Server are all free tools that you can use to do this.  (Note that VMware Server is not the same as VMware ESX.  ESX is an expensive enterprise product, where VMware Server is a free product.)

They're all pretty straightforward.

Comment: ESXi is a free bare-metal hypervisor. The difference between ESX and ESXi is that ESX comes with support and additional management modules/etc. for things like failover, backup, etc. while ESXi will create a standalone virtualization server.

Comment: Thanks - what the easiest to setup, my requirements are not that complex?

Comment: @Ravi I've been working in enterprise virtualization for some time, so they all seem fairly easy to me.  I would say that VirtualPC is probably the easiest, followed by VirtualBox, and VMware Server the least.  If you want to keep the VM running when you're not logged in, use VMware Server.  If you have a spare server handy, you could use ESXi like @Bart said, but you need to know what you're doing.  If you're fine with running it from your desktop, VirtualPC and VirtualBox will be fine.

Comment: @Bart ESXi is free, but requires it's own hardware.  And isn't exactly user-friendly.

Comment: @gWaldo-Yes, it does need it's own hardware, that's kind of implied by "bare metal hypervisor" :-)

Comment: I normally avoid hosting virtual systems on a workstation unless it's for testing or something like that. It just increases the odds of something going wrong if you're using a server that other people are relying on in a VM and your workstation service pack or update (or some other need to reboot) kills it suddenly, or something bogs down the server. If you do anything that you need to have running I normally go type one hypervisor.

Comment: As for user-friendly and knowing what you're doing, the only trouble we had with ESXi was needing the proper hardware (look at the compat list)...setup took ten minutes, and from there it was just using the vSphere management tool to set up the VM and copy .iso images over to install from. It really wasn't bad at all.

Comment: The hardest part in the end was just getting through the marketing speak to know what tool you need to install and going through the context menus to find the spot to transfer files to and from the file store on the ESXi server. Now...backing up stuff and planning for reliability are different issues, as ESXi doesn't have that built in and going commercial for those is expensive if you're just starting out with virtualization. You end up having to come up with plans for backing up VM's or backing up the file stores through hacks and downtime or online backup within the VMs...

Comment: @Bart - not to be a pedant, but really the only differences between ESX and ESXi now is that 1) ESXi doesn't have a service console and 2) 4.1 is the last release of ESX. Everything will be ESXi going forward. I just completed migrating our entire VMware cluster at $WORK to ESXi v4.1 and it does *everything* that ESX does, including full support from the mothership, VMotion, HA, FT, DRS, etc., etc. I think what you were getting at is that the free (non-vCenter-connected) verison of ESXi lacks these advanced features, though they're certainly possible when in a proper vCenter cluster.

Comment: @Bart, Those are all good points (and I'm coming from the same kind of background), but I still maintain that ESXi (and ESX and Hyper-V) all require a higher level of expertise to set up and maintain (especially the datastores and networking) than the other products do.  What they all do is essentially the same (which network port to use, and where do you want to save the files), but the more powerful tools are meant for more powerful admins.  Also the HCL barrier is not insignificant outside of the enterprise datacenter.

Comment: @gWaldo-You're right in that the HCL is not insignificant; most virtualization products today are picky about hardware that they support and won't install unless you have the specific hardware on the system. There was a "White Box" project out there where people were assembling $500 ESXi systems with hardware they tested as working, but you don't get "support" for it from the company. For testing purposes it does save money, though.

Comment: @ErikA-I can't argue one way or the other since I haven't upgraded our ESXi system in a bit, but I wouldn't be surprised at your news. ESXi *was* ESX, just without additional modules, as was my understanding. After all it is just Linux with a proprietary interface and set of modules for VMWare's API behind the scenes; there were "hacks" to get some functionality like SSH running using blind typing at the console, as I recall. And ESXi could "upgrade" to ESX with their license key added, as I recall. It was just crippleware.

Comment: @gWaldo-as for the expertise part I think it's subjective to a degree, but since virtualization is by definition playing with abstraction, it's hard to argue it doesn't take more expertise and understanding to use things like the filestore and backup and such working well. I'd probably say it's "different" rather than a higher level of expertise, though. I've seen people who maintain AS/400's that had trouble setting up Windows shared printers.

Comment: @Bart - well, as I stated, the fundamental difference between ESX and ESXi is that ESXi doesn't have a service console. Even if you enable SSH (which is officially supported now by VMware), you're only getting access to a very anemic shell, not the full shell like you'd get with the ESX service console. ESXi could never be fully upgraded to ESX and still can't. Functionality, though is nearly identical between the two. While the hypervisors may be the same, they're vastly different architectures.